# Passar dados AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Preciso passar essa informação `"token", "<?php echo $tokenAnuncio; ?>"`,

Nesta função:

```
function load_image_data(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/fetch.php",
        method:"POST",
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#image_table').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Como fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode colocar diretamente desta forma:

```
function load_image_data(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/fetch.php",
        method:"POST",
        data: { token: "<?php echo $tokenAnuncio; ?>" },
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#image_table').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

E para pegar esta informação na sua pagina fetch.php, é só utilizar o array global $_POST, exemplo:

```
$token = $_POST['token'];
```

Comment: Perfeito mano.... mto thx